# How to evaluate this integration by parts, evolving a laplacian

Tags: integration

Integrating by part
$\Omega$, bounded open set in $R^n$, $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ b a given function in $\Omega$. $u=(u_1,…,u_n)$, $p$ defined in $\Omega$, u is zero in the bondary. v has divergent equals to 0
…
integratin by parts the scalar product $(-\Delta u,v)$, we obtain
$\sum_{i=1}^n (grad u_i,grad v_i)=((u,v))$

How do i evaluate this integration by parts?

Does anyone recommend a book for integrating in high dimensions?

Comment: You may be looking for the `\nabla` command. $\nabla$. But I am sorry to say that I have not found a great source on integration in higher dimensions.

Comment: You introduced $f$ and $p$, but never seemed to need their introduction..? What is $((u,v))$ (are you defining it by your equality, e.g.)? Is $\Delta u$ defined as $(\Delta u_1, ..., \Delta u_n)$?

Comment: Oh sorry…was in a hurry and really didn't define ((u,v)).

Comment: Oh sorry…was in a hurry and really didn't define ((u,v)). $((u,v))=\sum_{i=1}^n (D^j u,D^j v)$, $D^j = D_1^{j_1}...D_n^{j_n}=\frac{\partial^[j]}{\partial x_1^{j_1}...\partial x_n^{j_n}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\nabla\cdot\left(\varphi\nabla\phi\right) = \nabla\varphi\cdot\nabla\phi + \varphi\nabla^{2}\phi
$$